# Stuck: hide/show divs with next button, redirect last div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I have so far, which allows the user to click an image to open a new window and go to a location. When that click occurs, the image in the parent window is replaced with the next div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rzTHw/

Here's the working code so far...

```
<div class = "box"><a href="link1.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/cf5/&text=img+1"></a></div>
<div class = "box"><a href="link2.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/f0f/&text=img+1"></a></div>
<div class = "box"><a href="link3.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/fb1/&text=img+1"></a></div>
<div class = "box"><a href="link4.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/444/&text=img+1"></a></div>​
```

Jquery:

```
$('.box').not(':first').hide();
$('.box a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var newWin = window.open(this.href,'newWindow'),
            that = $(this).closest('.box'),
            duration = 1200;
        if (that.next('.box').length){
            that.fadeOut(duration,
                         function(){
                             that.next('.box').fadeIn(duration);
                         });
        }
    });
```

What I am having trouble with is:

1. Creating a "next" button so the user can cycle through to the next div without having the click the image, thus avoiding having to open a new window to get to the next image.
2. Having a click on the last div redirect the window location to a URL, while still doing the normal function of opening a new window to the `a href` location if the image is clicked. Otherwise if clicking the "next" button when the last div is shown, simply redirect the user.

What's the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at tweaking your code to allow for a next button, and my best guess at what you want to happen for the last image:

```
var redirectUrl = 'http://www.google.com'; // replace in your code

function next(event, duration) {
    duration = duration || 1200; // default value
    var that = $('.box:visible');
    if (that.next('.box').length) {
        that.fadeOut(duration, function() {
            that.next('.box').fadeIn(duration);
        });
    } else {
        window.location.href = redirectUrl;
        // the above line doesn't work inside jsFiddle, but should on your page
    }
    return false;
}

$('.box').not(':first').hide();
$('.box a').click(

function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newWin = window.open(this.href, 'newWindow'),
        duration = 1200;
    next(e, duration);
});
$('.next').click(next);
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/dUa5L/1/). Note the redirect is prevented in some browsers since it is running inside an iframe. But it should work in a normal page.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks! I just noticed that `var newWin = window.open(this.href, 'newWindow'),` opens one window, which is used to load the href contents of all subsequent clicks.  In other words, if the user clicks on an image a second time, it loads the href URL in that same sibling window that was opened in the previous click, rather than opening a new window.  Any way to make that always open a new window?

Comment: Got it... just had to change `var newWin = window.open(this.href, 'newWindow'),` to `var newWin = window.open(this.href),` Thanks again.

Comment: @user1373779 Yup, the second parameter to `window.open()` is an "identifier" for the window, so if you reuse the same identifier, it will reuse the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at a slideshow jquery plugin. [JQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23) being just one example. There are plenty. Just google jquery Slideshow or jquery cycle and pick the one that suites you best. The cycle plugin itself has a number of "pager" examples that let you change the contents of the displayed picture without leaving the page.

Most of them offer having the contents be html and not just a simple picture so you can play around with what exactly you want.

There's also Fancybox, lightbox, colorbox, etc. if that's what you're trying to accomplish.